# Hierarchical naming to setItems Acrobat Pro

Tags: javascript, adobe, acrobat

As the title says I am looking to setItems on many comboboxes that all have the same prefix. No matter the method, I receive a calculation failed error. I am not sure how to build an array to contain all the field names but I have a feeling that is the best way forward. If anyone knows of a resource that instructs on building an array or if anyone knows an easy way to reference many fields that share a group name, please let me know.
Thank you for reading. I hope to hear from you soon.

Answer (score 0):

Calling [getArray](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/acrobat/acrobat_dc_sdk/2015/HTMLHelp/index.html#t=Acro12_MasterBook%2FJS_API_AcroJS%2FField_methods.htm%23TOC_getArraybc-11&rhtocid=_6_1_8_31_2_10) on the base field gets the array of child fields for the parent field.

```
var childFields = this.getField("basename").getArray();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. I tried recreating this code in a new file with a couple of comboboxes and it still says that (variable).setItem is not  function. I also tried using this to hide the fields. childFields.dispay=display.hidden  did not seem to register at all. Sorry to ask another question but did I do something wrong?

Comment: The code I added just gives you the array of child fields, you need to call setItems for each field in the array.

Comment: Ah I understand. This is handy for several things. If I understand correctly, I could do a for loop to go through the array and use that to set Items?